# modify the resolution to 1920x1200 on my archlinux through xrandr then the screen get black

Tags: archlinux, xorg, xrandr, x-dwm

one day I updated my archlinux through pacman -Syy. when I reboot then it get black,
and I try to fix it through close a series of command in .xinitrc
when I closed this command "xrandr -S 1920x1200" then the xorg was able to work just the word too small
I try to change other resolution but all could not work
Two day's latter I backed up my date in my laptop and reinstall archlinux xorg and dwm, the xorg couldn't work also.
thank's for your help

change my resolution to 1920x1200